# Unable to access couchbase node outside of docker

Tags: docker, couchbase

I have a couchbase docker setup. The container was up and running. I am able to access couchbase console using http://localhost:8091. But I see The couchbase node is still in docker host. I couldn't able to access this node outside of docker. But It was accessible inside docker.

Inside docker container

```
root@88c8efff0061:/# nc -v 172.19.0.17 8091
Connection to 172.19.0.17 8091 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
```

Outside docker

```
$ nc -v 172.19.0.17 8091
nc: connectx to 172.19.0.17 port 8091 (tcp) failed: Operation timed out
```

I exposed the following ports

```
+      - "8092:8092"
+      - "8093:8093"
+      - "8094:8094"
+      - "8095:8095"
+      - "8096:8096"
+      - "11210:11210"
+      - "11211:11211"
```

Because of this my queries are timed out. I couldn't able to proceed. How to solve this issue?

Comment: Why didn't you expose 8091?

Comment: You just need to add port 8091 to the port exposures. It's the only one not explicitly exposed. Or just do a range from 8091-8096

Comment: I exposed 8091 port too. Still I couldn't able to reach the query node

Comment: Is there only one node? Or have you set up multiple nodes inside of Docker?

Comment: one node in the couchbase cluster